# What happens if you try to save a PFObject that has been removed by another user?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

In my game I have a situation where the player can download a PFObject, and then make changes to it, however that PFObject on the server might be removed by another player, what would then happen if the original player then does a save command on that object? would it crash because it no longer exists on the server? would it create a new object with the same original data? ideally I want nothing to happen, but if there is an issue, is it possible to check if the PFObject still exists on the server before doing the save?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Parse for a while, and I think the "Save" operation will create a new object.
To prevent this, just like you said to fetch the object see if it still exists:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:theObject.objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(object) {
        // object exists then do the Save
    }
}];
```